# Is calling shell with prefined string safe?

Tags: python, security

So, this question occurred to me while I was reading the documents of Subprocess in python. So let's just use example, because programmers understand code.

```
from Subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def connect_with_netCat(port, ip):
  Popen('nc %s %s' % (ip, port), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

My question; is this safe? I know netcat is a poor choose for example since it also leaves vulnerabilities for an attacker to call that function and connect somewhere, but it was the first package that came to my mind for an example, but just looking at the code - is it safe since there's the constant in it?

Or would this be a safer way of doing this?

```
def connect_with_netCat(port, ip):
  from Subprocess import Popen, PIPE
  Popen('nc %s %s' % (ip, port), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Since it's outside the global scope. Just a curious question.

Comment: Use `%d` instead of `%s`, so that it will always format as a number. Then it can't accidentally inject other strings that have meaning to the shell.

Comment: Oops, `ip` isn't a number, it's a hostname or IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the source of `ip` and `port` are safe, then the command should be safe.

To be a little safer, you could leave out `shell=True`, since you're not making use of any shell syntax in the command. That way, if there are shell operators in the command, they won't be interpreted.

You should also use `%d` instead of `%s` for the port, since that's required to be a number.